# How does 取りあえず function in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

In this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8JEvkDc48M&t=2m37s

> 今回ですね、キャラクターがしゃべってくれるから、すごい楽なんですよ。
> *In this game (unlike previous ones), the characters speak, so it's really easy*
>
> しかも、オープニングテーマっていうのか？あれ、オープニングテーマでいいのかな
> *And then in the opening theme (movie) or whatever you would call it,*
>
> とりあえずそこでX5がで何が起こったかっていうのも、あらすじで言ってくれるんでね。助かりますね。
> *it recaps what happened in X5, which helps.*
>
> じゃあ、いきましょう。
> *OK, let's go!*

But: https://jisho.org/search/toriaezu

> 取りあえず
>
> 1. first of all; at once; right away​
> 2. for now; for the time being​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adverbial 取り合えず is not easy to translate in some contexts. I think it may help if you understand it as "anyway" or "for now". This usage sets aside what has just been said and starts a new topic that's unrelated or semi-related to the previous topic.

Let me give you my rendering of the middle section:

> しかも、オープニングテーマっていうのかな？ あれの…オープニングテーマでいいのかな？ ま、とりあえずそこでX5が、で何が起こったかっていうのも、あらすじ言ってくれるんでね。助かりますね。
> Moreover, in the... is that the opening animation? Can we call that the opening animation? **Anyway**, you see X5 in there, or if anything at all happens, a summary is given to us. Very helpful.